# How to have a form label and input field be inline when using wtf.form_field and bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, flask-wtforms

I am trying to create a form where the form label is inline with the field, vs above it.  I am using flask-wtf and bootstrap.

Using the code below, the default is to have the label above the field, and I can't figure out a way to have it inline, while still using wtf.form_field

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import 'bootstrap/wtf.html' as wtf %}

....

{{wtf.form_field(form.income, class='form-control', placeholder='Income'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        {{wtf.form_field(form.income, class='form-control', placeholder='Income'}}
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        {{wtf.form_field(form.income, class='form-control', placeholder='Income'}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this does not work.  This just gives 2 instances of having the label in one row and the field below, with that field taking the width of the screen (after fixing the syntax error with the missing ')' after the placeholder).  My goal is to have the label and input field on the same line while using wtf.form_field.